# why does hapi.js on heroku cause a transmit error when I use the reply.create()

Tags: heroku, hapi.js

I'm getting the following error when I try to send a 201 response in my app when it's on heorku.  It works fine on my local machine.

Code

```
reply({msg: 'foo'}).created();
```

Curiously, if I add a parameter to the created method, it doesn't throw an error in Heroku.  What's the difference in the environments that's causing the issue?

Error:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
Error: "name" and "value" are required for setHeader().
     at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.
     at Object.internals.transmit (/app/node_modules/hapi/lib/transmit.
     at /app/node_modules/hapi/lib/transmit.js:34:26
     at Function.internals.Auth.response (/app/node_modules/hapi/lib/auth.
     at /app/node_modules/hapi/lib/transmit.js:139:25
     at internals.Response._streamify (/app/node_modules/hapi/lib/response
     at internals.Response._marshal (/app/node_modules/hapi/lib/response.
     at /app/node_modules/hapi/lib/transmit.js:535:20
     at /app/node_modules/hapi/lib/transmit.js:119:18
     at Object.exports.parallel (/app/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/items/lib/index.js:47:9)
```

Comment: You using the same version of Node locally that heroku is using? Also, which version of hapi?

Comment: Latest version of everything, node, hapi, and heroku - though I'm not sure if the heroku node version is the same as my local.  I'll check tonight.  I added a parameter to the created function call and it works on heroku now.  I wonder why it errors in heroku and not locally.

Comment: Officially hapi, and all of the related modules, are only guaranteed to work with Node 0.10.x at present. You could try switching to that version locally and check what version heroku runs. If you ssh into the instance, you can do `node -v` to find out easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.created` function is expecting a `uri` parameter so that when the response `Location` header is set, it has a value. Try passing in a string into `created`, should fix your problem. Further down in the stack, there is a call to `setHeader` for "Location" but you haven't provided the value, thus the error.

Comment: that is indeed the error, but why would it work on local but not on heroku?

Comment: Different version of node.